# Centering div with border on the page

Tags: html, css, centering

I need to center div on my page. Dimensions are not fixed. Here is what I do to center it

```
background-image: url(../img/icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -3px black;;
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    width: 82%;
    top: 7.5%;
    left: 9%;
```

And this works fine if I don't have a border property set. If I set it to lets say 5px div is not horizontally centered anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add "box-sizing: border-box;". So the border does not extend your div. http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you so muck, I am not sure I can mark is as an answer as it is a comment.

Comment: Posted it as answer so you can mark it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like you are centring the DIV but rather hard coding the positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;`. So the border does not extend your div.

More box-sizing: css-tricks.com/box-sizing

Comment: Correct this keeps the DIV dimensions consistent with the border included, but it doesn't help centre the DIV.

Comment: But that was the OPs problem.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

also, `box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -3px black;;` should not have the 2nd semicolon.

Comment: margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto does not work on a position:absolute element

Comment: Like Edward said, use position:relative;

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.yourclass{
background:url(../img/icon.png) no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-0-background-size: cover;
border: 5px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
border-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -3px black;;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 85%;
width: 82%;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Just saying: When you use background method, you don't need to type like: "background-image" with "background-repeat: no-repeat", you can just type like "background:url(...) no-repeat" - making it smaller and more organized.

Comment: When using margin: 0 auto; to centre make sure the position is set to relative.